# Why can't I send my custom class through my webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization

I have these classes:

```
public abstract class CustomField
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public FieldType Type { get; set; } 

    public enum FieldType
    { 
        String = 0,
        Integer = 1,
        Boolean = 2,
        List = 3
    }
}

public class StringCustomField:CustomField
{
    public String Value { get; set; }
    public Int32 MinLenght { get; set; }
    public Int32 MaxLenght { get; set; }

    public StringCustomField()
    {
        this.Type = FieldType.String;
    }
}

public class CustomGroup
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public List<CustomField> FieldList = new List<CustomField>();
}
```

When I try to transfer `CustomGroup` through my webservice I get this error:

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Serialization is failing when C# tries to transfer my `StringField` through my `CustomField`.

What am I doing wrong?

Marc Gravel tell me to do that and i understand the solution but some thing is wrong, no effects, cath the same error!! , help!!

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(StringCustomField))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(IntegerCustomField))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(BooleanCustomField))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ListCustomField))]
public abstract class CustomField
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public FieldType Type { get; set; } 

    public enum FieldType
    { 
        String = 0,
        Integer = 1,
        Boolean = 2,
        List = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: it's Length, not Lenght. However, I was under the impression that it was the deserialization that would be the problem when you use subclasses. Unfortunately I can't remember exactly how I solved it. Look into XmlArrayItemAttribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx)

Comment: Downvotes were due to poor/unprofessional formulation of question, edits have taken care of that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending subclasses as xml, you will need `[XmlInclude]`:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(StringCustomField))]
public abstract class CustomField
{...}
```

You can add multiple `[XmlInclude(...)]` markers for any other subclasses in the model.

Comment: Marc something change im my scenary when i recompile the solution and try to update de service reference on client side i catch an error talking about System.Xml not found, now if i solve this!!XD

Comment: If you get the same error, why mark as answered? I don't know what the System.Xml thing is without looking.

Answer (score 1):

`List<CustomField>` will serialize and deserialize to a `CustomField[]` if you're using a web service, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
public class CustomGroup
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public List<CustomField> FieldList = new List< StringCustomField >();

}
```

instead

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is at all semantically correct.  Perhaps there are other derived classes that we don't know about (seems likely) that would be included in the FieldList.

Comment: Yes more tree!! BooleanCustomField, IntegerCustomField, ListCustomField!!! The sample above solve my problem for only one derived class!!

Comment: That isn't valid in any version of .NET, including 4.0

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you should 
1. connect your web service to your app
2. use the namespace of the WS, so all the classes will be used from the Proxy
i don't think that the local class will be understood by the remote web serivce correctly, even if you're using the same assembly on both parties

Comment: the objects is wornking on both sides, there is no problem to me!!

Marc Gravell get my problem!! I try the solution now!! thanks opetrov!!